# how can I shut off all these xcode build or linking info lines?

Tags: xcode, build

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2. When I build and debug I see in the Xcode debug panel many dozens or hundreds of lines like each of the following sample lines:

```
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

and this:

```
dladdr(0x33a1f000, 0x1e54d318)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace, 0x00000010)
dladdr(0x339f2000, 0x1e54d348)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager, 0x00000010)
dladdr(0x33608000, 0x1e54d378)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference, 0x00000010)
dladdr(0x358e4000, 0x1e54d3a8)
```

and this:

```
_dyld_image_count()
_dyld_get_image_header(0)
_dyld_get_image_header(1)
_dyld_get_image_header(2)
_dyld_get_image_header(3)
```

and this:

```
dlsym(0x1e578f90, gldGetVersion)
dlsym(0x1e578f90, gldGetVersion)
dlsym(0x1e578f90, gldCreateDevice)
dlsym(0x1e578f90, gldDestroyDevice)
dlsym(0x1e578f90, gldPopulateRendererInfo)
dlsym(0x1e578f90, gldChoosePixelFormat)
```

Each of the above is only a small fraction of the groups of similar lines. In all I'm seeing hundreds of lines like these. I suppose they are telling me something about the linking that's going on but I don't know what exactly.  I must have turned on a build setting at some point that caused them to appear. Now I'd like to turn it off again. Can anybody say what setting controls the appearance of these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your project's scheme in Xcode, navigate to the Diagnostics tab and uncheck "Log Dyld API Usage" and "Log Library Loads." The former is far more verbose.

Comment: I cannot find these two options on XCode 11. Where can I find them?

Comment: For XCode 11 and above: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292278/where-to-find-log-dyld-api-usage-and-log-library-loads-on-xcode-11)