# Where to find "Log Dyld API Usage" and "Log Library Loads" on XCode 11?

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11, dyld, dynamic-loading

I want to disable the printing of Logging Dynamic loader events (dyld) in the XCode console. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965664/7650556).
But I couldn't find **Log Dyld API Usage** and **Log Library Loads** options in product scheme diagnostics of XCode 11. Please help me find them.

PS: If there is a new process in Xcode11 for disabling logs, please let me know.

Answer: This step by step solution is suggested below in the answers. I am just attaching this picture for a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Please, don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271337/how-to-disable-logging-dynamic-loader-eventsdyld-in-xcode) in 24 hours. If you'd like to add more information, clarify it, narrow it down to Xcode 11 only, just edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dynamic loader

- [Events environment variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/LoggingDynamicLoaderEvents.html)

One would say that you can set environment variables like `DYLD_PRINT_APIS=0`, `DYLD_PRINT_APIS=false`, `DYLD_PRINT_APIS=no`, ... but it doesn't work in this way. Check the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-732.8/src/dyld2.cpp.auto.html):

```c
else if ( strcmp(key, "DYLD_PRINT_APIS") == 0 ) {
    gLogAPIs = true;
}
```

In other words `gLogAPIs` is `true` when the variable exists. You can set it to whatever value, keep it empty, it will be always enabled if the variable exists.

## Xcode scheme

UI for this setting is gone in the Xcode 11, but it can still be in the scheme file. Let's say that you have a simple project `Foo`. The scheme is located at `Foo/Foo.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Foo.xcscheme`<sup>1)</sup>. It's a XML file. Quit Xcode and open this file in any editor and search for the `LaunchAction` element.

There will be:

- `LaunchAction` element attribute like `enableAddressSanitizer = "YES"`<sup>2)</sup> or
- `DYLD_...` environment variable set.

Just remove this attribute/environment variable and you should be fine.

---

<sup>1)</sup> The exact path can vary, because it the scheme can be included in the workspace, project, ...

<sup>2)</sup> I don't have a previous version (10) of Xcode installed, can't check for the exact name, but it should be there and it will be obvious which one it is. This one, I used, is for the Address Sanitizer checkbox. If you find the exact name, let me know and I will update this answer or answer it yourself and I'll delete this one.

[image]

---

**Update**

Instructions above helped OP to find exact XML element names. One has to remove:

- `LaunchAction/AdditionalOptions/AdditionalOption` elements
- where the `key` is either `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` and/or `DYLD_PRINT_APIS`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving a detailed explanation. I found `xcschemes` under `project.xcodeproj` file (I didn't find them under `project.xcodeworkspace`). Opened the `file.xcscheme` from terminal and deleted `<AdditionalOptions>` under `<LaunchAction>` instead of deleting `<EnvironmentVariables>`. Now all the Logging Dynamic loader events (dyld) stopped printing in the console.